# .items() reading a dictionary as a list and throwing an attribute error

Tags: python, list, dictionary, types, items

I am using IN-CORE, a analysis platform for natural disasters. I am working with a Monte Carlo definition in their library (pyincore). I am using this code to run through a list of dictionary entries of damage states for different infrastructure locations.

```
failure = []
for i in range(10):
    print(damages[i]) # prints {'DS_0': Decimal('0.6716138851'), 'DS_1': 0, 'DS_2': 0, 'DS_3': Decimal('0.3283861149')}

    print(damages[i].items()) # prints dict_items([('DS_0', Decimal('0.6716138851')), ('DS_1', 0), ('DS_2', 0), ('DS_3', Decimal('0.3283861149'))])
    damage_interval_keys = ["DS_0" , "DS_3"]
    failure_state_keys = ["DS_3"]
    (MonteCarloFailureProbability.calc_probability_failure_value(damages[i], damage_interval_keys, failure_state_keys))
    
print(failure)
```

However, I get this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[167], line 9
      7     damage_interval_keys = ["DS_0" , "DS_3"]
      8     failure_state_keys = ["DS_3"]
----> 9     (MonteCarloFailureProbability.calc_probability_failure_value(damages[i], damage_interval_keys, failure_state_keys))
     11 print(failure)

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\pyincoreEnv\lib\site-packages\pyincore\analyses\montecarlofailureprobability\montecarlofailureprobability.py:329, in MonteCarloFailureProbability.calc_probability_failure_value(self, ds_sample, failure_state_keys)
    327 count = 0
    328 func = {}
--> 329 for sample, state in ds_sample.items():
    330     if state in failure_state_keys:
    331         func[sample] = "0"

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I made sure the list of the dict entries wasn't layered in another list, but as the code above prints, the .items() works outside of the function call and the .dtype returns that the list at a certain index is a dictionary. I am quite confounded, so any help would be amazing.

Comment: `calc_probability_failure_value()` is probably supposed to be invoked on an *instance* of `MonteCarloFailureProbability`, rather than on the class itself.  This causes the parameters to be shifted over by one - so your dict is interpreted as `self`, and your `damage_interval_keys` list is interpreted as the dict.

Comment: When you compare `(MonteCarloFailureProbability.calc_probability_failure_value(damages[i], damage_interval_keys, failure_state_keys))` with `MonteCarloFailureProbability.calc_probability_failure_value(self, ds_sample, failure_state_keys)`  `ds_sample` is a list called `damage_interval_keys`

Comment: To clarify the above comments if needed, the error message shows the function signature, and it doesn't match with how you're calling it. I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but I skimmed the docs and it looks like you're supposed to [initialize `MonteCarloFailureProbability` with an `IncoreClient` then pass in `damage_interval_keys` via `.set_parameter()`](//incore.ncsa.illinois.edu/doc/incore/notebooks/Joplin_testbed/Joplin_testbed.html#mcs-chaining-with-joplin-building-damage).

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title and make a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're calling the method on the class, rather than an instance, the first argument is being used as `self`, not `ds_sample`, and the list `damage_interval_keys` is being used as `ds_sample`.

Create an instance of the class first, and call the method on that.

```
sim = MonteCarloFailureProbability()
failure = []
for i in range(10):
    print(damages[i]) # prints {'DS_0': Decimal('0.6716138851'), 'DS_1': 0, 'DS_2': 0, 'DS_3': Decimal('0.3283861149')}

    print(damages[i].items()) # prints dict_items([('DS_0', Decimal('0.6716138851')), ('DS_1', 0), ('DS_2', 0), ('DS_3', Decimal('0.3283861149'))])
    damage_interval_keys = ["DS_0" , "DS_3"]
    failure_state_keys = ["DS_3"]
    (sim.calc_probability_failure_value(damages[i], damage_interval_keys, failure_state_keys))
    
print(failure)
```

There's other problems, though -- you're printing `failure` at the end, but nothing updates that. Are you missing a call to `failure.append()` with the results of the call?

Comment: Ah, yes! This is what I was missing. I was copying over old code, and I think the sim = MonteCarloFailureProbability() was in a part of the original that got deleted. Thank you so much! As for the append stuff, that was part of the original code I had, but I was messing with it to make sure other small things weren't throwing the error. So I can add it back now.